# Repeat function execution for n seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to run `x` function for `n` seconds. What I tried:

```
var stop = false;

setTimeout(function(){stop = true}, n);

while(!stop) x();
```

but this didn't work... As I understood the reason is that setTimeout waiting until no task is running and then executes the function. Is that right?

Another way to do this is like this:

```
var stop = false, started = Date.now();

while(!stop) {
    if((Date.now() - started) > n) stop = true;
    else x();
}
```

Is there any other better way?

Comment: Seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: The question is how many times by seconds should it be done? Because a while loop will actually freeze everything else. This also means that your function will be run a impredictable number of times

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times, do things until x seconds or milliseconds passed and then stop repeating execution

Comment: Maybe you should look into requestAnimationFrame (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var stop = false;

setTimeout(function(){stop = true}, n);

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(!stop){x();}else{clearInterval(interval);}
}, 0);
```

the while statement will block the timeout function, if you don't mind using setInterval, you can do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

i will do like this

```
var t = new Date().getSeconds() + 10; // 10 seconds

while(new Date().getSeconds() <= t)
{
   //loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule it repeatedly while time's not up:

```
var runRepeatedly = function(f, secs) {
  var start = Date.now();
  var reschedule = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - start < secs * 1000) {
      setTimeout(repeat, 0)
    }
  }
  var repeat = function() {
    f();
    reschedule();
  };
  repeat();
}

...

runRepeatedly(x, n);
```

Note that `x` should not take too long to return.

Answer (score 0):

**Here my solution:**

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop time</button>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```